# Python : Map function with none type list as parameter

Tags: python, list, nonetype, map-function

I want to pass a list of None in a map function but it doesn't work.

```
a = ['azerty','uiop']
b = ['qsdfg','hjklm']
c = ['wxc','vbn']
d = None

def func1(*y):
    print 'y:',y

map((lambda *x: func1(*x)), a,b,c,d)
```

I have this message error:

```
TypeError: argument 5 to map() must support iteration.
```

Comment: Note that it looks like you want `itertools.starmap()` over `map()` given the function you are making (which does nothing, but was probably meant to be `lambda x: func1(*x)`). Note that whatever you do here, `d` will cause a problem.

Comment: Actually, given that `d = None`, I think it's more likely the OP wanted the behavior of `map(..., (a,b,c,d))`, and assumed that `None` would call the function with no parameters.

Comment: @Lattyware: Not quite; `map()` with multiple lists *zips* the lists. `starmap()` applies the lists one by one instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I was drawing the use of `starmap()` from the weird `lambda` - if the asker did want the `zip()`-like behaviour, then combining `starmap()` and `zip()` would work fine.

Comment: @Lattyware: to get this to work with `starmap` and `zip` gets quite verbose; the `map()` syntax is more compact here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `None` with an empty list:

```
map(func1, a or [], b or [], c or [], d or [])
```

or filter the lists:

```
map(func1, *filter(None, (a, b, c, d)))
```

The `filter()` call removes `d` from the list altogether, while the first option gives you `None` values to your function call.

I removed the lambda, it is redundant here.

With the `or []` option, the 4th argument is `None`:

```
>>> map(func1, a or [], b or [], c or [], d or [])
y: ('azerty', 'qsdfg', 'wxc', None)
y: ('uiop', 'hjklm', 'vbn', None)
[None, None]
```

Filtering results in 3 arguments to `func1`:

```
>>> map(func1, *filter(None, (a, b, c, d)))
y: ('azerty', 'qsdfg', 'wxc')
y: ('uiop', 'hjklm', 'vbn')
[None, None]
```

You could use `itertools.starmap()` as well, but that gets a little verbose:

```
>>> list(starmap(func1, zip(*filter(None, (a, b, c, d)))))
y: ('azerty', 'qsdfg', 'wxc')
y: ('uiop', 'hjklm', 'vbn')
[None, None]
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `lambda *x: func1(*x)` is exactly equivalent to `func1` (besides a pointless extra function).

Comment: i have another question, if i have a var `u='string'` and my function func1 is like that : `def func1(z,y*)` how i pass my argument u in my map function?

Comment: @Tof: use [`functools.partial()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial): `map(partial(func1, u), ...)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it's perfect!! but just to find out, there is another solution?

Comment: You could use a lambda as well, but that is slower; `partial()` operates entirely in C, avoiding a python stack operation.

Answer (score 0):

Make 2nd argument to map a list or tuple:

```
map((lambda *x): func1(*x)), (a,b,c,d))
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message pretty much says it all: `None` is not iterable. Arguments to `map` should be iterable:

```
map(func, *iterables) --> map object

Make an iterator that computes the function using arguments from
each of the iterables.  Stops when the shortest iterable is exhausted.
```

Depending on what you want to achieve, you can:

- change `None` to an empty list;
- `map` your function on a list of `[a, b, c, d]`

Also note that you can map `func1` directly, without a lambda:

```
map(func1, *iterables)
```

Answer (score 0):

2nd argument d should be a SEQUENCE , make it as a list or tuple..